# Management of two content types in same list through access

Tags: 2013, content-type, access

I have 2 content types in the same list. Some fields are in 1st content type, some in the second and some are shared. I defined a default content type. When i open with access and try to enter a line it always refers to the default content type and i can't select which content type i can enter, is there any solution to manage content types through access ?

Comment: Does this happen to you only when you create a new item or even when editing an existing item?

Comment: editing and creating

Comment: And when you edit the item there is no option to change content type?

Comment: Nope. From Access if i modify the secondary content type it shows me that i need to fill in required fields in the default content type and doesn't store my modifications.

Comment: But it is ok when i fill in from the infopath form.